# saving locations in background every minute without NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, background, save, location

I am currently saving locations in background. I need latitude, longitude and NSDate which is why I went with CLLocation instead of geopoint. I am trying to figure out how to save locations only every minute or so, as I currently have one element each second. 
I cannot use NSTimer as my app still needs to obtain these updates after the authorised delay of running code when in background.
Any suggestion of how this might be done ?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Viktor

Comment: When you get a location update, save a time stamp. When you get the next update compare the current time with the time stamp. If it is more than a minute then save the location and update the time stamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This is what I was trying to achieve. I have decomposed my location object to retain the timestamp and I would only save the object is the second was 00. I was wondering though if the code was to be executed as the app would be in background.

Comment: Checking for second of 0 isn't reliable - you might get an update at 59 and then another one at 01.  You should check for a difference >= 60.  `didUpdateLocations` will be called in the background, but it will stop being called if your app is killed.  Significant location change mode will re-launch your app if required.  You could also consider adding a minimum movement distance to reduce the frequency of updates to save battery

Comment: What I do is converting timestamp into nsdate, using components to extract second. And applying an "if" condition, whereas second == 00, then I save the element. This actually works, I end up saving only locations taken every minute, with second of 00. This solution actually works like a charm. I was concern that, even though I have found a github piece of work online to keep tracking location in background and when the app is terminated, the additional code to filter the location updates were to be executed.  I guess testing on real device will unveil the mystery.

Comment: As long as you are doing the work in `didUpdateLocations` then it will continue to work until the app is killed or the device restarted.  Your time stamp method seems a bit complicated compared to simply calling `timeIntervalSinceDate:` and comparing for >= 60

Comment: Now regarding the second matter of the drastic battery drainage constantly updating location would impact, I have highly considered using significant changes. However, I dont exactly know how would the process work, to re launch the app when required, as you have suggested. As the ideal scenario would be to use significant changes until users share same locations or arrive in same area. Even though I applied an approximate radius in location difference when comparing users', I believe the inaccuracy of significant changes wouldnt allow me to identify when users are in same place, to relaunch..

Comment: On this note though, Paulw11, I very much appreciate your help. Thank you infinitely for sharing ideas.

Comment: If you are using significantLocationChange then iOS will relaunch your app as required. Are you using Parse.com? If so it is probably much more efficient to compare locations in cloud code whenever a user location is updated and send a push notification to the relevant devices notifying them of another user's proximity

Comment: You are here providing me with very relevant information. I will, thanks to you, investigate further the cloud code comparison option, which I did not know of until now. I am using Parse, yes. Thanks again Paul, extremely helpful.

Comment: @Paulw11, I have tried you solution for saving only location elements every x minute. However, I might have got it wrong, as I was saving a timestamp that I would then compare, however the timestamp would update as time goes by and consequently, I would never get the ability to obtain the desired difference with the next element I wish to save. Could you expand a little on this option, could you perhaps illustrate it with an example if that is not too much asking ?   Thanks a million.

Comment: No worries, got it !   Thanks @Paulw11, I can even delay it by more than a minute this way. All good to go here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to come back and add some sample code. I'm glad you worked it out.

Comment: Hi Paul and Viktor! Im calling a method from CMMotionActivityManager class called queryActivityStartingFromDate:date to get a history list of activities for a day. Im filtering those activities by putting a activity_startdate and end date and if the activity exists for more than 2 mins, Im showing it on a table view or else im discarding that activity. I hit this method every 2 minutes to get the user's latest activity. Sometimes it shows few seconds less for 2 mins and gets discarded. I dont understand why the time duration changes. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read: [Getting the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10),
there are important notes about battery life.

IMO it's better to rely on the framework callbacks and not try to put a timer on it.

You may also consider region monitoring..

Maybe you can give us more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I am trying to same users' locations and time at which it was captured to identify when users were in same location as the same time. I considered region monitoring but my situation applies to users who are mobile I didnt think it would be an appropriate solution.